# Riemann hypothesis for the Hecke operators and modular forms

Tags: modular-forms, riemann-hypothesis, hecke-operators

Let $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n) e^{2i \pi nz}$ be an eigenform of  $S_k(\Gamma_0(N))$. Since the Hecke operator acts by $T_p f = a_p f$ the Riemann hypothesis for $f$'s L-function is 
 $$ \!\!\! \!\!\! \!\!\! \!\!\!(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s})^{-1} =\prod_p (1-a(p) p^{-s}+p^{k-1-2s}) =\frac{\displaystyle[\prod_p (1-T_p p^{-s}+p^{k-1-2s})] f(z)}{f(z)}  \tag{1}$$ converges and is analytic for $\Re(s) > k/2$.

> Then, the Riemann hypothesis for all the eigenforms of $S_k(\Gamma_0(N))$ is that
>   for any $f \in S_k(\Gamma_0(N))$, 
>   $$[\prod_p (1-T_p p^{-s}+p^{k-1-2s})] f(z) \quad \text{ is analytic for } \Re(s) > k/2\tag{2} $$

**Questions :**

This suggests to define a Riemann hypothesis *for the Hecke operators themselves*, and I would like to know if there is a well-known way to think about that.

- The RH for the Hecke operators could be the convergence in operator norm of $\lim_{x \to \infty} \prod_{p \le x} (1-T_p p^{-s}+p^{k-1-2s}),$ for $\Re(s) > k/2$, with the norm  coming from the Petersson inner product.
- But there are other possible norms, for example  $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^\infty f(ix) \overline{g(ix)} x^{2 \sigma -1}dx$. Indeed, the choice of the norm is a major problem : when defining $\displaystyle T_p f(z) = p^{k-1}\sum_{ad =p, b \bmod p} d^{-k} f(\frac{az+b}{d}) \tag{3}$ the statement in $(1)$ works the same way whenever $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n e^{2i \pi n z}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s} = \prod_p (1+a_p p^{-s}+ p^{k-1-2s})^{-1}$, no matter that $f$ is modular or not, so that in general $f$ doesn't have a Riemann hypothesis (nor the $T_p$ operator acting on it). So we really need a norm and a statement specific to modular forms, for example about $\prod_p (1-T_pp^{-s}+\langle p \rangle p^{k-1-2s})$ (which works for $S_k(\Gamma_1(N))$ too).

  For short, RH is believed true for Dirichlet series with Euler product and functional equation. $\prod_p (1-T_p p^{-s}+p^{k-1-2s})$ is just an Euler product. So hopefully, we only need to add a reference to the modularity (implying the functional equation) to make a viable RH statement.
- Assuming we solved that part, the Hecke operators depend on $N$ only for finitely many $p$, so can we expect the statement to imply the Riemann hypothesis for $\displaystyle\bigcup_N S_k(\Gamma_0(N))$ ? In that case, what's about the dependence on $k$ ?

  Also looking at the  weight-$\frac{1}{2}$ forms $\sum_{n \ge 1}^\infty \chi(n) e^{2i \pi n^2 z}$ could help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but note that Hecke did not have the Petersson inner product to work with so was not able to diagonalize the space.  All his work is in terms of operators.

Comment: @Stopple : For computing the operator norm coming from the Petersson inner product we need a basis of $S_k(\Gamma_0(N))$, so it isn't really different from $(1)$ and $(2)$. But changing the norm leads to a problem : the statement works the same way for functions having no RH. There is also the possibility to introduce things like $\langle p \rangle$ to make it specific to modular forms. Thus my question : what is the best way to think about all this, and is there a nice statement deserving to be called the RH for the Hecke operators ?

Comment: Have you tried to consider the automorphism group of all the Hecke operators endowed with a suitable structure and to show that the analogue of RH you conjecture to exist is a property preserved under its action?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN you mean the modularity (or functional equation) of the functions onto which the Hecke operators act (I added a statement about this)

Comment: It is definitely not a good approximation to reality to suggest that Dirichlet series with Euler products and analytic continuation and functional equation satisfy a Riemann Hypothesis: Landau already had the example of $\zeta(2s)\zeta(2s-1)$ or similar. Also, to claim an RH for Dirichlet series taking values in Hecke operators would be asking for RH for all newforms and oldforms and linear combinations (with the same eigenvalues), which certainly could fail, without further discrimination.

Comment: @paulgarrett I think you missed a point. Non eigenforms don't have a RH but it is not a problem because if $f \in S_k(\Gamma_0(N))$ then $f(z) = \sum_{j=1}^J c_j f_j(z)$ where $f_j(z)$ are eigenforms with L-function $F_j(s)$ so that $[\prod_p (1-T_p p^{-s}+ p^{k-1-2s})] f(z) = \sum_{j=1}^J c_j \frac{f_j(z)}{F_j(s)}$, which is the observation justifying the RH is a property of the Hecke operators, not only of the eigenforms.

Comment: @reuns, I'm not sure that it works that way, but perhaps I just don't understand your intended point... That is, bad-prime factors can change things, especially "oldform" complications, by taking linear combinations of things that otherwise _do_ have an RH (conjecturally). That is, multiplicities (which would appear for symplectic groups, for example) of Hecke eigenvalues create complications, to my perception.

Comment: @paulgarrett "RH is true for all the eigenforms $f_j$ of $S_k(\Gamma_0(N))$" iff "for each $j$ : $[\prod_p (1-T_p p^{-s}+ p^{k-1-2s})] f_j(z)$ is analytic for $\Re(s) > k/2$" iff "for each $f \in S_k(\Gamma_0(N))$ :  $[\prod_p (1-T_p p^{-s}+ p^{k-1-2s})] f(z)$ is analytic for $\Re(s) > k/2$". I don't follow why oldforms could be a problem (and I don't know the adelic or symplectic world).

Comment: @reuns, I'm not meaning to dispute the possible truth of RH for all cuspidal L-functions attached to GL(2), for example, ... but I am uneasy about an assertion for "Hecke operators", as (e.g.) a (commutative) algebra of (e.g., convolution) operators. If the scope of these operators were delimited somehow, I'd start believing in the possibility that an RH-type assertion was not immediately implausible. (Just being a bit paranoid here, maybe...)

Comment: @reuns, seeing your last comment: at good primes, old forms and new forms give the same L-function, by anyone's definition. But/and if one defines an L-function simply as a Mellin transform, the bad-prime factors may vary (in essentially artifactual, as opposed to meaningful, ways). Then by deliberately arranging linear combinations to do mildly perverse things, RH can be (reasonably, unsurprisingly) violated. So, suitably interpreted, for $GL_n$ something like this could be plausible, by multiplicity-one. But the latter is known to fail (at least in naive forms) for other classical groups.

Comment: @reuns, not to introduce a pole or singularity, but just meaningless off-line zeros, _finite_ linear combinations of the sort you just mentioned can create such effects. Thus, I think, a good statement/conjecture should manage to _avoid_ such things. E.g., only refer to newforms, which in various possible ways grabs the easy classical information at good primes, and dodges ambiguities at bad primes. But/and the latter must be dealt with somehow, and it cannot be trivial, I think. (And, again, for other classical groups, the multiplicity-one feature tends to be lost...)

Comment: @paulgarrett Hi, I left the Hecke operators alone, but I'm now interested in "RH for the Dirichlet series with functional equation". Say $F(s)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s},\Lambda(s)=\Gamma(s/2) q^{-s}F(s) = \varepsilon  \Lambda(1-s)$. Then the RH is $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^N \mu(k) \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{nk} (nk)^{-s} = a_1$ for $\Re(s) > 1/2$. On the modular side it becomes $\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_0^1 |\sum_{k=1}^N \mu(k) f_k(ix)| x^{\sigma-1}dx < \infty$ for $\sigma > 1/2$ where $f_k(z) = \sum_{n \ge 1} a_{nk} e^{2i \pi nk z}= \frac{1}{k}\sum_{b=0}^{k-1}f(z+\frac{b}{k})$

Comment: The idea is that for a general Fourier series $f(z)$ then $\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_0^1 |\sum_{k=1}^N \mu(k) f_k(ix)|^2 x^{\sigma-1}dx < \infty$ doesn't have any reason to converge, and to find how the modularity changes the deal and would make it convergent. Intuitively, it could lead to statements about $\mu(k)$ implying the GRH. Also, trying to prove the equivalent of the PNT in this setting should be interesting.

Comment: Well, modularity in a too-amorphous sense is insufficient: e.g., for a quadratic field extension of $\mathbb Q$ with absolute ideal class group having a sufficiently large $2$-part, we can make that number of unramified Hecke characters whose Dirichlet series have the same functional equation, have Euler products, and are attached to modular forms for $GL(2)$. But then it is trivial to make real-linear combinations of three or more having a zero at any given (e.g., off-line) location. But this linear combination does not have an Euler product, of course.

Comment: @paulgarrett Say $F(s)= \prod_p \frac{1}{1-a(p) p^{-s}}$ has a completely multiplicative Euler product, then the RH for $F(s)$ is $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^N \mu(k) a(k)k^{-s} F(s) = 1$ for $\Re(s) > 1/2$. My trick is to replace $a(k)k^{-s} F(s)$ by $F_k(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a(nk)(nk)^{-s}$. Then look at $\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^N \mu(k) F_k(s)= a(1) \quad \text{for } \Re(s) > 1/2 \quad(eq.1)$. This statement works when $F$ is replaced by a linear combination of $L$-functions. With $F(s)=\zeta(s)+L(s,\chi)$ then $(eq.1)$ implies $\frac1{\zeta(s)}+\frac{1}{L(s,\chi)}$ is analytic

Comment: @paulgarrett Hi. Don't you think there is a lot to say about that ? ${}{}{}{}$